# prove that a space with a Schauder basis is separable, that is, it contains a countable dense subset.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, schauder-basis

[image]

[image]

[image]

Q: I can't get the sketch of the proof
Now since an arbitrary element of $X$ having the expansion $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n b_n$ in terms of $(b_n)_{n \in N}$ can be written as $\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n b_n,$ it follows that $X = \overline{span(\{x_n : n \in N\})}$ so $span(\{x_n : n \in N\})$ is already dense in X. what we prove then?

Also, i see that proof for the same theorem
[image]

Q: why because $\overline{span(\{x_n\})} = X$ then it is suffices to prove that $A$ is a dense subset of $span(\{x_n\})$

Comment: $\mathrm{span} (\{x_n\})$ is not countable, but $\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{Q}} (\{x_n\})$ is.

Comment: thank you very  much

Comment: but i see another proof for that theorem where he prove that $span_Q(\{x_n\})$ is a dense subset of $span({x_n : n \in N})$ not of X. is this all right? why?

Comment: If the metric space $X$ is dense in $Y$ and $Y$ is dense in $Z$ (all equipped with the same metric induced from $Z$) then $X$ is dense in $Z$.